# Possible permutations of a given digit

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, permutation

*This is the code to find out the possible permutations of a given digit..., is there any possibility to decrease the code*

```
from itertools import permutations
lst=[int(x) for x in input()] #taking input and split
perm = list(permutations(lst))
for i in range(0,len(perm)):
    perm[i]=int("".join(map(str,perm[i])))#join them and covert to int
print(perm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(input())]
```

Comment: can i have the output in the int format it is returning str to the list

Comment: `perms = [int(''.join(p))for p in permutations(input())]` will give you a list of ints instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations
lst=list(map(int,input().split()))
perms1 = [int("".join(map(str,i))) for i in list(permutations(lst))]
print(perms1)
```

Comment: This is much less efficient than the accepted answer. There is no reason to convert the input to `int`, then convert to `str` for the `.join()` and then back to `int`.